# Which of these is my JDK path, and which is JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, java-home, linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint and am trying to configure SpringSource Tool Suite which requires you to direct it to the system "JDK path". Although I haven't explicitly downloaded/installed Java on this system yet, when I ran the update manager I did see Open JDK get installed and found several directories under `/usr/lib/jvm` (see screenshot below). My questions are:

- Spring Tool Suite requires you to specify a path to the JDK, and my question is, which one do I choose, and why?; and
- How do I tell which of these is my `JAVA_HOME`?; and
- What's the difference between the "*JDK path*" and `JAVA_HOME`?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

> echo $PATH --> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
>
> java -version -> java version "1.7.0_03"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu3)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
>
> which java -> /usr/bin/java

Comment: What do you see if you print your `echo $PATH` or run `java -version` or `which java`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Spring Tool Suite requires you to specify a path to the JDK, and my question is, which one do I choose, and why?; and

This can only be answered according to the needs of your application.  Do you need the stability of Java 6 or the features added in Java 7?  Are there APIs you intend to use that are only available in Java 7 or are the Java 6 libraries sufficient?  Do you have customers that require the use of one JVM over another?  Only you can answer these questions.

> How do I tell which of these is my JAVA_HOME?; and

You will want to make JAVA_HOME reference the specific JVM environment that you've decided on for your project.  For example, if you decide on Java 6 you'll probably want to set your JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64.

> What's the difference between the "JDK path" and JAVA_HOME?

The JDK path refers to the Java Development Kit - which includes the java compiler, debugger and other tools associated with developing java programs.  JAVA_HOME can reference either the JDK root or the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) root directory when running java programs; but you should, for development purposes, always have JAVA_HOME reference the JDK root.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin (+1) - however I have once concern. Please look at the contents of `java-6-openjdk-amd64`. It consists of 3 subdirectories: `man`, `bin` and `jre`. The `bin` directory only contains `javaws`, and the `jre` directory only contains `java` and `javaws`. I think these are both incomplete Java (JDK/JRE) installs. Do you know if Linux Mint comes with incomplete installs, and whether or not I should just download the version of Java that I want myself (through package manager), or if these are sufficient for some weird reason. I just don't see any of the normal executables under Java.

Comment: Also, if I set JAVA_HOME to be Java 6, will this conflict with the fact that running `java -version` shows `Java 1.7.0_03` to be the running version of Java on the system, or will the very act of setting JAVA_HOME change the output of `java -version` itself?

Comment: I personally use Oracle's JVM and am not personally familiar with Linux Mint.  My development environments are typically RHEL or Gentoo based (both using Oracle's JVM) and installed via the system package management tools.  I would look into (re)installing the JDKs via your system package tool.

Comment: WRT setting JAVA_HOME; this depends on the /usr/bin/java script, which may or may not respect your environment settings.  Not being a Linux Mint user I cannot tell you for sure one way or another.  Many systems have a configuration tool that allows you to set the specific version of a package that has concurrent installations.